# Rails 3.1 and Twitter Bootstrap modal don't play nice?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.1, twitter-bootstrap

I'm tearing my hair out over this one:

I'm trying to use the Twitter Bootstrap modal (v.1, not 2) to post comments via AJAX, using the standard TB modal attributes for the div:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="commentModal">
<div class="modal-header">
    <a href="#" class="close">×</a>
    <h3>Say Something</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <%= render 'common/error_messages', :target => @comment %>
    <%= form_for [@commentable, Comment.new], :remote => true do |f| %>
      <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
      <%= f.text_area :content, :size => "84x5" %>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <%= f.submit "Comment", :class => "btn primary",:id => "submitButton" %>
</div>
    <% end %></div>
```

Clicking the link fires the modal fine, and whether or not I remove the `remote => true` the post is created fine (one reloads, the other doesn't). But I can't seem to have the `create.js.erb` action fire ANY javascript, even just to hide the modal, much less append the comment:

```
$('#commentModal').modal('hide');
```

However, if I hijack the click event, I can hide the modal fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    $('#commentModal').modal('hide');
    return false;
});
```

});

This, of course, defeats the typical Rails structure of passing through the create action to the js.

Can anyone show me how to use the Twitter Bootstrap modal to post a comment via AJAX? One proviso: the comment posting methodology needs to be model-independent, since I want to use the code on a bunch of models (polymorphic association).

Or let's just start by showing me how to dismiss the freakin' thing via a controller action....

As always, thanks.

Comment: Have just discovered this article: [link] (http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms-data-type-with-jquery/) and expect it to solve my problem one way or the other. Will post tomorrow for the benefit of others. Basically, I believe I have some malformed js elsewhere in my app that is causing problems.

Comment: This question/answer also sheds light on why I've been confused using the pre-v.2 Bootstrap:[link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8183693/how-do-you-specify-the-primary-and-secondary-actions-for-a-bootstrap-modal-windo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the benefit of those interested, the above links were crucial to me figuring out how to make this work. Following is the final version of my `create.js.erb` file, based on those explanations. Of particular interest is the binding to the modal, specific to Bootstrap:

---

```
var el = $('#new-comment-form');

<% if @comment.errors.any? %>

  // Create a list of errors
  var errors = $('<ul />');

  <% @comment.errors.full_messages.each do |error| %>
    errors.append('<li><%= escape_javascript( error ) %></li>');
  <% end %>

  // Display errors on form
  el.find('.modalerrors').html(errors).slideDown();
  el.find('.modalerrors').delay(5000).slideUp();


<% else %>


$('#commentModal').modal('hide');

// Clear form
el.find('input:text,textarea').val('');
el.find('.modalerrors').empty();

// Render a partial to display the comment here-- "prepend" if you want the most recent first, "append" if you want it last
// You must hide the rendered comment before prepending to show it with an effect
// Bind the show effects to when the modal is 'hidden' -- Use 'one' to avoid duplication if someone makes multiple comments before reloading

  $('#commentModal').one('hidden', function () {
     $('<%= escape_javascript(render( @comment )) %>').hide().prependTo('#comments').show('drop',{}, 500, function() {
        $(this).effect("highlight",{color:"#C3FFB5"}, 2000);          
     });
  });

<% end %>
```

Comment: Just upgraded to Bootstrap V.2 and jQuery 1.7, and the @comment rendering code now throws a syntax error.

Comment: Actually, it was jQuery 1.9, through jquery-rails gem update v. 2.2, which has a stricter way of parsing HTML. Couldn't get it to work using recommended $.parseHTML() call, so rolled jquery-rails gem back to 2.1.4, and all is well.